# O que é " : " (dois pontos) em C#?

Tags: c#, for, sintaxe

Ainda não entendi o que os dois pontos representa e o motivo desse código não estar rodando.

```
int soma = 0;
        int[] lista = { 3, 7, -6, 10, -1, 0, -1, 4};

        for (int i : lista)
        {
            if (i > 0) { 
            soma = soma + i;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Soma: " + soma);
```

Comment: Olá, Misaell. Seria importante [edit] a pergunta com mais detalhes (qual o erro, já que diz que não funciona, e complementar com uma breve explicação do que esperava que o código fizesse - referências são bem-vindas) para verificarmos se tem relação com a sintaxe mencionada (parte esta que já foi explicada pelo @Maniero) ou se são dois problemas separados.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 8):

Neste contexto é erro de sintaxe. Em hipótese alguma os dois pontos pode ser usado aí em C#.

Em Java esta sintaxe do `for` seria válida e seria equivalente a isto em C#:

```
foreach (int i in lista)
```

Como não há dois pontos em outra parte do código imagino que está confundindo linguagens. Então até se tentar compilar isto dará um erro de sintaxe, por isso ele não está rodando. Assim roda:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var soma = 0;
        foreach (var i in { 3, 7, -6, 10, -1, 0, -1, 4}) if (i > 0) soma++;
        WriteLine("Soma: " + soma);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1lzWjD). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RbmS2J). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Sum.cs).